# Insert into SQL database user input from HTML form

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert into column "UserId" in my sql database, using php, text that the user inputs in the HTML form. 
Below is a basic example to help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<form action="index1.php" method ="post" name="trial">

    <input type="text" name="testName" id="testId">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xx";
$dbname = "wp";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$UserId = $_POST['testName'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO UserProfile (UserId) VALUES ('$testName')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Some notes:

1. I can connect to database and insert in the correct columns checkbox and radio values from the form
2. I cannot find a way to insert in the database the user text input from the form (UserProfile is the table and UserId the column). 
   Would using a javascript variable, like below one, help?

   ```
   var testVar = document.getElementById("testId").value;
   ```
3. I know I am opening myself to hacking using the above code, I would like to improve it later on but I think I need to first figure out the basics (ie: how to get the user text input added to the database)

Than you in advance for any help!

Comment: Does the `$conn->error` trigger, and if so, what does it say?

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all?

Comment: no, no errors at all. just the the userId I input in the textbox doesn't get input in the database.

Comment: you have `$UserId` not `$testName`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @JigarShah what do you mean? can you explain where do you think I am making a mistake? thank you

Comment: You are declaring `$UserId` but you're trying to insert `$testName`. Which is whats wrong!

Comment: should be : `$sql = "INSERT INTO UserProfile (UserId) VALUES ('$UserId')";
`

Comment: @Jigar Shah says right

Comment: "I know I am opening myself to hacking using the above code, I would like to improve it later on but I think I need to first figure out the basics" — Doing it the right way (with prepared statements and bound variables) means throwing out a large portion of the code you are writing. It's a false economy, you are just teaching yourself bad habits.

Comment: @JigarShah Thank you!! Now it works!

Comment: @Quentin Taken onboard - looking into this now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

you are storing the value in $UserId, not in $testName:

Change your SQL Query to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO UserProfile (UserId) VALUES ('$UserId')";
```

I think this will help.
BTW: Think about SQL-Injection! Look here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Look here

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO UserProfile (UserId) VALUES ('$testName')";
```

Change $testName to $UserId in sql statement because it's the name of your new variable in php:

```
$UserId = $_POST['testName'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO UserProfile (UserId) VALUES ('$UserId')";
```

But I advice you to:

1- use PDO for any sql handling in php

2- use mysqli_real_escape_string to protect your code from threats.

make it like:

```
$UserId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['testName']);
```

Comment: Please do not give answers with security vulnerabilities

Comment: what is wrong in security in my code sample? explain to me please i'm confused now!!!!

Comment: Google prepared statements using mysqli

Comment: Thank you, i am editing it to explain him how to protect the insert